# python sqlite3 CREATE TABLE escape using list as headings?

Tags: python, sqlite, escaping

I am trying to use a list as headings in my sqlite3 table using this code:

```
import sqlite3 as lite

headers = ['Id', 'Name', 'Price']

con = lite.connect('test.sqlite3')

with con:

    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE Cars(? INT, ? TEXT, ? INT)", tuple(headers))
```

However I am getting this error:

```
OperationalError: near "?": syntax error
```

Any ideas on how to get this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQL queries from Python, placeholders (such as `?`) are only allowed where **values** would be -- actual data.  For **meta**data like names of tables and fields, you unfortunately need string substitution.

So in this case

```
qry = 'CREATE TABLE Cars({} INT, {} TEXT, {} INT)'.format(*headers)
cursor.execute(qry)
```

Of course, this **does** expose you to a risk of SQL injection if the `headers` come from an untrusted source -- no way to **safely** accept **meta**data from an untrusted source, you'll have to scrub/verify the query yourself before sending it on.

Comment: Thanks I used something similar:  qry = 'CREATE TABLE Cars(%s INT, %s TEXT, %s INT)' % tuple(headers).   But I am a new programmer using python and sqlite3 for data analysis so I am not familiar with SQL injection hacks.   Is it an issue if I use this code for offline purposes? Where can I read more about removing vulnerabilities from my code?

Comment: Read about SQL injection at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection .  If `headers` is under your complete control you're fine; if it comes from untrusted user input you're not -- `headers[0]` might be `foo INT); DROP TABLE Cars` &c, soon crashing your system.  See http://xkcd.com/327/ for the most famous example:-).  BTW, if you found my A helpful, *accept* it -- i.e clic on the checkmark-shaped outline to its left; that's core StackOverflow etiquette.